# EventLog bug in reading value of logEntry.EntryType

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, logging

i have a code to get the information from eventlogs.

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
   EventLog eventLog = new EventLog("Application", ".");

   getEvents(eventLog.Entries);
     }


private void getEvents(EventLogEntryCollection  eventLogEntryCollection)
    {

        foreach (EventLogEntry logEntry in eventLogEntryCollection)
        {                
            if (logEntry.Source.Equals("yen"))
            {
                eventType.Add(logEntry.EntryType.ToString());
                eventTime.Add(logEntry.TimeWritten);
                eventSource.Add(logEntry.Source);
                eventCategory.Add(logEntry.Category);
                eventID.Add(logEntry.EventID);
                eventMsg.Add(logEntry.Message.ToString());
                Global.logger.Info("Level = " + logEntry.EntryType.ToString() + ", eventTime = " + logEntry.TimeWritten);
            }
        }
    }
```

so the logEntry.EntryType.ToString() sometimes returns me Information, Error, Warning and sometimes just a 0. what is this 0 for??

Please any suggestions

the logs show this:

> INFO 01-Jun-2011 11:48:18.SSS    8 .Global - Level = Information, eventTime = 5/20/2011 3:19:08 PM
>    INFO 01-Jun-2011 11:48:18.SSS    8 .Global - Level = 0, eventTime = 5/20/2011 3:19:16 PM

Answer (score 1):

This can only happen if your eventlog is somehow corrupt. What does happen when you try to view this event with the eventvwr.msc? I have seen many corrupt event logs. This does usually happen when many events are logged at the same time. I never have found a clear repro but this does happen even on Windows Server 2008 from time to time although the whole eventlog subsystem has been rewritten.

Comment: in the eventvwr.msc both the levels are Information.. If it was corrupt it should have shown some mistake.. all the other values are fine except the level, where i get 0 sometimes... thanks though.. please let me know if you find any more info

Answer (score 0):

The [`System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.eventlogentrytype.aspx) enumumerations defines five values: `Error`, `FailureAudit`, `Information`, `SuccessAudit` and `Warning`. But if you take a look to the [documentation to native WinAPI `ReportEvent` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363679.aspx) you will see there are actually six types of events. The event with code 0 is `EVENTLOG_SUCCESS` which have the same description as `EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE`. It is also displayed the same as "Information" by the Event Viewer.

So probably logEntry.EntryType.ToString() == "0" means that the event was logged with type of `EVENTLOG_SUCCESS`.